# Under what conditions does the reference count in Python increment/decrement?

Tags: python, reference

I know that in Python, garbage collection for an object is triggered when an object's *reference count* reaches 0.

https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/intro.html#objects-types-and-reference-counts

But I'm struggling to understand what exactly are the conditions that trigger the increment/decrementing of the  reference count.

In particular,

(1) I know the count is incremented for each *reference* to an object... but I don't know exactly what is meant by a *reference* in the context of Python. I'm struggling to understand how references differ from, say, names or variables. What exactly is a *reference* in Python? (examples extra-appreciated)

and

(2) 
What are the conditions which trigger the decrementing of the reference count?

Comment: "Every variable in Python is a reference (a pointer) to an object and not the actual value itself. For example, the assignment statement just adds a new reference to the right-hand side.

To keep track of references, every object (even integer) has an extra field called reference count that is increased or decreased when a pointer to the object is created or deleted. " [Garbage collection in Python: things you need to know](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/)

Comment: @DarrylG What triggers the deletion of pointers a.k.a variables? If you are willing to bear with a few more questions to help me further understand what's going on and post an answer, I'd be glad to upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: @asker-hi Asker, no problem answering questions.  In Python variables refer to objects and each object has a reference count of how many variables are referred to it.  As the article mentions examples of increasing the reference count includes assignment statements, adding object to a container such as a list,  etc. Complementary, things that would decrease the reference count are reassigning a variable (previous object count decreases new one increases) and removing it from a list.

Comment: @DarrylG Thanks a lot, your explanation was clear and helped me understand what references are now. I also see why re-assignment or list removal would remove the reference. I'll accept this as an answer if you would like to post it as such.

Comment: @DarrylG Another question I have is, why do reference cycles prevent the count from going to 0? For example, in this article (https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/) it says that self-referencing objects have a non-zero reference count. But I'm not sure why that would have to be the case. Is it just a quirk of the CPython implementation? (Thanks in advance for any further help, btw, I don't expect it as it's not strictly related to OP, but would appreciate it.)

Comment: @asker--tried to answer your question about reference cycles.  Hope this helps.  But, feel free to ask more questions if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Why do reference cycles prevent the count from going to 0?

[Reference](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/)

Things which increase reference count includes:

1. assignment operator
2. argument passing
3. appending an object to a list

Consider the following code:

```
lst = []           # assignment => (ref count + 1) for related object
lst.append(lst)    # append to list => (ref count + 1) for related object
```

After the two steps above -> reference count = 2 (+1 for each step)

However, this has created a reference cycle.

```
del lst # decreases reference count by 1
```

Now, reference count = 1.

But, no variables refer to this object so the reference count won't change.

And, regular garbage collection won't remove it since ref count > 0.

So with regular garbage collection, this leads to what's referred to as a "memory leak" (i.e. memory that's not referred to but can't be released).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. From what I understand, `del lst` un-assigns the variable `lst` from the underlying object. But, after `lst.append(lst)` it seems the object just becomes the nested list `[[]]`, right? If so, why is there still a reference to `lst` even after the name has been un-assigned (i.e. `del`eted)?

Comment: @Asker--think of it as having a table of variable names (i.e. namespace) with references they point to.   Statement `lst = []`  adds `lst` to the table pointing to object at address `id(lst)`.  The issue is with the later `del lst` the reference count for the object becomes 1 and lst is removed from the namespace.  The namespace doesn't refer to the object but the object's reference count > 0.  This is where normal garbage breaks and more sophisticated techniques come in.

Comment: It seems `lst = []` creates a reference to `[]`, while `lst.append(lst)` changes the underlying list object to be `[[]]`. Since `lst.append(lst)` changes the underlying object, doesn't that actually remove the earlier reference, so that now there's only one reference, `lst`, to the object `[[]]`?

Comment: Try: `lst = []; print(id(lst)); lst.append(lst); print(lst)`.  You will see that id(lst) does not change with the append, meaning lst still refers to the same memory starting address.